# How to use VBA to convert text in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, styles, accessibility

I want all our old Word documents at the Uni to start to have accessible styles applied. For this test, I want to set up a macro to search a Word doc and wherever it finds 11pt Arial, I want it to apply an Accessible Style which will be Verdana 11pt. In doing this, it means academic staff could more easily convert non-accessible documents into more accessible documents.

I've started learning macro and can create one which saves the Word file out to PDF, which is a useful shortcut but I'm struggling.

I've tried creating a macro to open Replace, look for any instances of Arial 11pt and then replace them all with another style, but when I run it, it seems to apply my alternative style but also adds weird boxes to the document.

Also, if I apply the Header Style to the doc and then manually edit that style to be Arial 11pt then when I run the macro, the text seems to get the new Style applied but what I see is still Arial, and I get the weird boxes!

I would love to crack this on my own but it's not an area I am familiar with so any help from the community would be fantastic.

Here's the macro code, which I created using the recorder:

```
Sub Style()
'
' Style Macro
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find.Font
        .Size = 11
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Written Stuff")
    With Selection.Find.Replacement.ParagraphFormat
        With .Shading
            .Texture = wdTextureNone
            .ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorBlack
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBlack
        End With
        .Borders.Shadow = False
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

In this example, instead of using Verdana I'm using Algeria so I can more easily see the font changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a text attribute Font="Arial 11pt" and then want to apply a Paragraph style. Probably attributes applied to text of a paragraph have a higher priority than the attributes of the style of the parapgraph.

When you say "Also, if I apply the Header Style to the doc and then manually edit that style to be Arial 11pt then..." you are NOT manually editing the *style* but are editing the *text* of a pragraph that has a style. (Editing the style would mean editing the definition of the style, and the style can have been applied to many paragraphs).

You can do two things:

- Replace the text-level font  with the text-level new font, or
- Remove the text-level font attribute and apply the paragraph style.